# Fetch many to many relationship table data

Tags: php, mysql

I was trying to fetch data from following tables.

> table_question

```
q_id | question     
 1   |   q1   
 2   |   q2
 3   |   q3  
 4   |   q4
```

> table_answer

```
a_id| answer 
 1   |   a1   
 2   |   a2
 3   |   a3  
 4   |   a4    
 5   |   a5
```

> table_entity

```
e_id| q_id | a_id 
1   |   1  |    1 
2   |   1  |    3
3   |   2  |    2
4   |   2  |    4
5   |   3  |    5
6   |   4  |    2
```

I want a question and answer. Please give me some suggestion.
Fetche data by using doctorine 2 ORM.

Comment: Hi, can you show us the query which you tried to run. any code from your end will surely help us understand.

Comment: Please check my edited question

Comment: Please check my answer i have wrote a mysql code for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this mysql with your phpmyadmin

```
$qry = "SELECT quetion.que,answer.ans FROM entity INNER JOIN quetion ON quetion.id=entity.q_id Inner Join answer On answer.id=entity.a_id";
```

There are use join table for join those table and get the data from those table

Comment: If this working for you then you can mark this as answer :)

Comment: I already marked

Comment: How to fetch using doctorine 2 ORM

Comment: You can generate another question for this with your code then it's easy for answer

Answer (score 0):

you need to use join query. With joining both table you can get all tables relational data

```
 $query = SELECT table_question.question,table_answer.answer FROM table_entity INNER JOIN table_question ON table_question.id=table_entity.`q_id ` Inner Join table_answer On table_answer.id=table_entity.a_id ;
```

Comment: Please check my edited question and give the answer

Comment: this sql query tested ..

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
SELECT table_question.question, table_answer,answer FROM table_entity
JOIN table_question ON (table_entity.q_id = table_question.q_id)
JOIN table_answer ON (table_entity.a_id = table_answer.a_id)
```